# Laravel-5.5 gives 401 status

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5, and i am sending an ajax request on success of another ajax request to another URI and getting "419 unknown status". I know there is something to do with the CSRF_token, I included "Meta tag" according to docs and also included in "ajaxSetup" according to docs but it still shows me the 419 error. Any suggestions ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the XSRF token on request data of debug console?

Comment: Yes, i can see X-CSRF-TOKEN in headers under network in console.